# java.net.ConnectException in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, websocket, localhost

I have seen this issue being addressed in some other threads, but I am not able to resolve my problem. So I am asking this again.

I have created a Tomcat WebSocket server with Eclipse, and created a WebSocket client application with Android Studio. In order to pass information between the server and client, I have used my Laptop IP Address to connect the two. But, when I run the application, I am getting this error,

**Error!: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1(port 80):connect failed:ECONNREFUSED(connection refused)**

I am not able to understand why the application is trying to connect to localhost, when I am connecting it through the machine ip address?

Below codes are used to connect to the socket server

```
public class WsConfig {
    public static final String URL_WEBSOCKET = "ws://100:76:32:184:8080/StartuptalksSocketsServer/chat?name=";
}

client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET
            + URLEncoder.encode(name)), new WebSocketClient.Listener()
```

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never done Android studio but just want to ask. Is `100:76:32:184` a correct ip address?

Comment: yes it is correct. I am using a dial up connection

Answer (score 0):

You should try to print in the console the variables:

1.WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET
2.URLEncoder.encode(name)

Before calling the function WebSocketClient, to be sure is not an allocation problem.

And if you still without a solution you can access to the object WebSocketClient, and again make a print inside to be sure that the variable is right in the method.

GL bye!